# How to turn on authentication for nancy modules as default behavior

Tags: c#, authentication, nancy

Authentication can be enabled for nancy modules by calling `RequiresAuthentication` in module's constructor:

```
public class CustomModule : NancyModule
{
    public ConfigurationModule()
    {
        this.RequiresAuthentication();

        // ... specify module
    }
}
```

Is it possible to enable authentication per default and add support for disable it?

I know that it is possible to subclass NancyModule and using the subclass instead, but that is not the way I would like to do it. I want to load modules that do not reference one of my custom assemblies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortuantelly, I didn't find a solution without referencing a custom assembly.

Finally, I came up with the following solution:

```
public abstract class CustomNancyModule : NancyModule
{
    protected CustomNancyModule(bool requiresAuthentication = true, string modulePath = null)
        : base(modulePath ?? string.Empty)
    {
        if (requiresAuthentication)
        {
            this.RequiresAuthentication();
        }
    }
}
```

and a corresponding bootstrapper implementation that ensures that all modules derive from `CustomNancyModule`:

```
public class CustomBootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override IEnumerable<ModuleRegistration> Modules
    {
        get
        {
            var modules = base.Modules;
            var customModuleType = typeof(CustomNancyModule);

            foreach (var module in base.Modules)
            {
                if (!module.ModuleType.IsSubclassOf(customModuleType))
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(
                        $"Module '{module.ModuleType}' is not a sub class of '{customModuleType}'. It is not allowed to derive directly from NancyModule. Please use '{customModuleType}' as base class for your module.");
            }
            return modules;
        }
    }
}
```